# c# regex: how to do an OR match?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to know how I can pass an OR regex expression. I tried `"(u|^upload)"` but this doesn't seem to work and instead catches anything I type

```
  var regex = new Regex("(u|^upload)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  return regex.IsMatch(msg.Text);
```

I expect it to catch u or U or upload or Upload

Comment: @heemayl no only u or upload nothing else, up would be invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct pattern would be:

```
^(u|upload)$
```

Where `^` and `$` are [anchors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx) that match the start and end of the string, respectively. This means that the pattern will only match the *entire* string or nothing at all.

But for that matter, you don't *really* need regular expressions at all:

```
var values = new[] { "u", "upload" };
return values.Contains(msg.Text, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Just for illustration, an equivalent pattern would be:

```
^u(pload)?$
```

This will mach any string that starts with `u`, optionally followed by `pload`, followed by the end of the string.

Note however, neither of these will *just* match `u`, `U`, `upload`, or `Upload`. Thanks to `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, they would also match `UPLOAD` or `uPlOaD`. If you only want to match exactly those four options you could do:

```
var regex = new Regex("^[uU](pload)?$");
```

Or (using [group options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
var regex = new Regex("^u(?-i:pload)?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Or without regular expressions:

```
var values = new[] { "u", "U", "upload", "Upload" };
return values.Contains(msg.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Test this to match the strings start with 'u' or 'U',and end with 'e' or 'E'.And the charactor 'u' or 'U'.

```
([uU].*?e)|([uU])
```

Or you can use this to match 'update' , 'Update' , 'u' and 'U'.

```
([uU]pdate)|([uU])
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture both u and U or upload and Upload use this

```
([uU]|[uU]pload)
```

If you want it at the beginning of the string:

```
^([uU]|[uU]pload)
```

If you want this to be checked against the entire string use:

```
^([uU]|[uU]pload)$
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/jX9bX0/2)